# How do I get the interface IP address from of a Cisco IOS configuration?

Tags: python, cisco, ciscoconfparse

When using the following Cisco IOS configuration, how do you get the interface IP address of `GigabitEthernet1/3` with `CiscoConfParse()`?

```
!
hostname Example
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 description Example interface
 ip address 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.128
 no ip proxy-arp
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 ip address 192.0.2.129 255.255.255.128
 no ip proxy-arp
!
end
```

I tried using this, but it throws an AttributeError...

```py
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
config = """!
hostname Example
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 description Example interface
 ip address 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.128
 no ip proxy-arp
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 ip address 192.0.2.129 255.255.255.128
 no ip proxy-arp
!
end
"""

parse = CiscoConfParse(config.splitlines(), syntax='ios', factory=False)
intf = parse.find_objects("interface GigabitEthernet1/3")[0]
print(f"GigabitEthernet1/3 address: {intf.ipv4}")
```

This throws an AttributeError...

```py
AttributeError: The ipv4 attribute does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two techniques to do this:

- To access the `ipv4` attribute of a Cisco IOS interface, you need to parse with `factory=True`; this returns an [`IPv4Obj()`](http://www.pennington.net/py/ciscoconfparse/api_ccp_util.html).
- You can also get the IP address as a string from `find_child_objects()` and `factory=False`.

#### factory=True and the `ipv4` attribute

Explicitly...

```py
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
config = """!
hostname Example
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 description Example interface
 ip address 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.128
 no ip proxy-arp
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 ip address 192.0.2.129 255.255.255.128
 no ip proxy-arp
!
end
"""

parse = CiscoConfParse(config.splitlines(), syntax='ios', factory=True)
intf = parse.find_objects("interface GigabitEthernet1/3")[0]
print(f"GigabitEthernet1/3 address: {intf.ipv4}")
```

```bash
$ python example.py
GigabitEthernet1/3 address: <IPv4Obj 192.0.2.129/25>
$
```

Note that the `factory=True` feature is experimental.

#### factory=False and `find_child_objects()`

You can also get the interface IP address as a string by parsing with `factory=False` and use `find_child_objects()`...

```py
>>> from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse, IPv4Obj
>>> config = """!
... hostname Example
... !
... interface GigabitEthernet1/1
...  description Example interface
...  ip address 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.128
...  no ip proxy-arp
... !
... interface GigabitEthernet1/2
...  shutdown
... !
... interface GigabitEthernet1/3
...  ip address 192.0.2.129 255.255.255.128
...  no ip proxy-arp
... !
... end"""
>>> parse = CiscoConfParse(config.splitlines(), syntax='ios', factory=False)
>>> obj = parse.find_child_objects("interface GigabitEthernet1/3", "ip address")[0]
>>> addr = obj.re_match("ip\saddress\s(\S.+)")
>>> addr
'192.0.2.129 255.255.255.128'
>>> IPv4Obj(addr)
<IPv4Obj 192.0.2.129/25>
>>>
```